# Moment generating functions...which distributions to use?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

**Q: You hired a terrible programmer and the moment generating function for the distribution of software bugs is M(t) = (1 - $\theta$t)$^{-\alpha}$. Groups of bugs can be detected within $\mu$ = 47 lines of source code with a standard deviation of sqrt($\sigma$) = 308.**

I solved for a and theta, but what the hell do they mean in this context??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moment generating function is that of a gamma distribution.  If you look up "gamma distribution wiki", you'll find the moment generating function and that $\alpha$ and $\theta$ are shape and scale parameters, respectively.  (And you can click on "shape" and "scale" on that page to find definitions of those terms.)

Of course, this only addresses your question about what $\alpha$ and $\theta$ represent.